# Java Eclipse-GEF Editor: Add mouse listener on elements

Tags: java, eclipse-gef

I have taken over an eclispe project with a GEF Editor where various items can be created into the editor. My task is to do soemthing if a double click occures on one of those items.
I have no knowledge about GEF in any way. How do I register a listener on an item put into the GEF editor?

I'm trying to make my way through the source code but I get lost to easy. Do I need a policy for that?

Comment: I stated that in my solution, yes. I don't know how to mark it as duplicate.

Comment: that comment automatically added when I mark it as duplicate :)

Comment: Thank you for claryfying that :)